# Question about xcode warning method definition 'XXX' not found

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I have seen something here[1](http://www.iphonedevbook.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=2023) that states that I can remove these errors in xcode 3 by changing a method like -(IBAction) shakeShakeShake to -(IBAction) shakeShakeShake (id) sender

I am using iphone sdk 3.0 and xcode 3.2.1 on snow leopard

My errors are:

Classes/MainViewController.m:156: warning: 'MainViewController' may not respond to '-shakeShakeShake'

/Users/temp/Desktop/src/Count Down Timer (Utility App)/Classes/MainViewController.m:156:0 /Users/temp/Desktop/src/Count Down Timer (Utility App)/Classes/MainViewController.m:156: warning: (Messages without a matching method signature

Classes/MainViewController.m: At top level:

Classes/MainViewController.m:467: warning: incomplete implementation of class 'MainViewController'

Classes/MainViewController.m:467: warning: method definition for '-pickerView:' not found

Classes/MainViewController.m:467: warning: method definition for '-shakeShakeShake:' not found

----- (sorry about the long error msgs, I tried to cut them down by removing compiler and path info) ---

I have tried adding things like

```
-(void)shakeShakeShake: (id) sender ;
```

as a prototype to the .h file and to the .m file

```
- (IBAction) shakeShakeShake: (id) sender {
```

dimView.alpha = 0.0f ; 
}

Making these changes will make the warning go away, but when I run my program and execute this function, it will exit to the Springboard with a console message:

> [MainViewController shakeShakeShake]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1213a20
>   2009-12-21 02:19:17.389 Count Down Timer (Utility App)[43704:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[MainViewController shakeShakeShake]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1213a20'

When I change the function back to - (IBAction) shakeShakeShake {
 (even if I leave the prototype style in with : (id) sender), the program (a simple utility timer) runs fine and gives no errors to the console.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I was always taught to remove warnings if possible as they may note problems that only surface later and are hard to find.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? thanks very much for your patience, I'm still new at this! ;-)

Thanks Piesia

BTW, shakeShakeShake is called here:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
  //Your code here
  [ self shakeShakeShake ] ;
 }
}

---- error msgs follow

Classes/FlipsideViewController.m:401: warning: incomplete implementation of class 'FlipsideViewController'
Classes/FlipsideViewController.m:401: warning: method definition for '-pickerView:' not found
Classes/FlipsideViewController.m:401: warning: method definition for '-shakeShakeShake' not found

Comment: looking here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/

I see that:

"Like the class declaration, the class implementation is identified by two compiler directives—here, @implementation and @end. These directives provide the scoping information the compiler needs to associate the enclosed methods with the corresponding class. A method’s definition therefore matches its corresponding declaration in the interface, except for the inclusion of a code block."

Comment: And here:
The instance (or member) variables of the class are declared in a code block that is delineated by braces ({ and }). Following the instance variable block is the list of methods declared by the class. A semicolon character marks the end of each instance variable and method declaration."

and here "The declaration of a method consists of the method type identifier, a return type, one or more signature keywords, and the parameter type and name information. Figure 2 shows the declaration of the insertObject:atIndex: instance method"

Comment: "This declaration is preceded by a minus (-) sign, which indicates that this is an instance method. The method’s actual name (insertObject:atIndex:) is a concatenation of all of the signature keywords, including colon characters. The colon characters declare the presence of a parameter. If a method has no parameters, you omit the colon after the first (and only) signature keyword. In this example, the method takes two parameters."

Comment: "When you want to call a method, you do so by messaging an object. A message is the method signature, along with the parameter information the method needs. All messages you send to an object are dispatched dynamically, thus facilitating the polymorphic behavior of Objective-C classes.

Messages are enclosed by brackets ([ and ]). Inside the brackets, the object receiving the message is on the left side and the message (along with any parameters required by the message) is on the right. "

I think that I am following these rules.  Thanks for any help Piesia

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I need to give the sender parameter explicitly as follows in the message call:

```
//instance method declaration
- (IBAction) shakeShakeShake: (id) sender ;


- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
if (event.type == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {

// message -- method signature + parameter information
        [ self shakeShakeShake: self ] ;

}
}
// ^-- needed for shake

//instance method definition
- (IBAction) shakeShakeShake: (id) sender {

    // make window clear
    dimView.alpha = 0.0f ;      // always undim screen in shake as a failsafe
}
```

When I do it like this, the warnings go away and the app seems to work. Thanks for your time. Piesia

Comment: I removed the method declaration of shakeShakeShake from FlipsideViewController.h as it wasn't used in this class.

The missing pickerView method was because my method declaration was missing a parameter!  Regards, Piesia