# Method definition not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

using Xcode 5.1, Objective-C

Just start to try use of Objective-C, write a simple program, and got some Warning :

> Method definition for "some method" not found...

I'm looking in to my code and I see method in implementation file (.m)
Screen.

[image: image of warning]

I know - see a lot of similar questions:

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11977385/2012219) - differences in letter case - check all it's ok
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5249053/2012219) - calling to method that not exist in .m file - check -
  exist
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710721/2012219) - same problem like in prev. question
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24328842/2012219) - weird/non-standard setup Apple - all OK
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4761101/2012219) - incorrect implementation
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941107/2012219) - missed parameter, so incorrect implementation
- and other same errors...

So according to this post, I think that the problem is or in missing declaration/implementation or some syntax's error

Check my code looks like all is ok.

---

Declaration - in .h file

```
//- mean non static method
//(return type) Method name : (type of var *) name of var
- (void)addAlbumWithTitle : (NSString *) title
//global name of var : (type of var *) local name of var
               artist : (NSString *) artist :
              summary : (NSString *) summary :
                price : (float) price :
      locationInStore : (NSString *) locationInStore;
```

Implementation in .m file

```
- (void)addAlbumWithTitle:(NSString *)title
               artist:(NSString *)artist
              summary:(NSString *)summary
                price:(float)price
      locationInStore:(NSString *)locationInStore {
Album *newAlbum = [[Album alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                        artist:artist 
                                       summary:summary 
                                         price:price  
                               locationInStore:locationInStore];
[self.albumList addObject:newAlbum];
}
```

I'm just few a day like start to try Objective-C with Xcode, maybe I something missed

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: try few times - first time i have few errors and few warnings, now left just one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Your .h should look like this for this method (remove extra colons):

```
- (void)addAlbumWithTitle:(NSString *)title
               artist:(NSString *)artist
              summary:(NSString *)summary
                price:(float)price
      locationInStore:(NSString *)locationInStore;
```

Apple Docs:

> If you need to supply multiple parameters, the syntax is again quite
>   different from C. Multiple parameters to a C function are specified
>   inside the parentheses, separated by commas; in Objective-C, the
>   declaration for a method taking two parameters looks like this:
>
> `- (void)someMethodWithFirstValue:(SomeType)value1 secondValue:(AnotherType)value2;`
>
> In this example, value1 and value2
>   are the names used in the implementation to access the values supplied
>   when the method is called, as if they were variables.

Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH3-SW8).